# How do I copy value in different column from previous row if the cell is not empty?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have the following situation:

```
A                   B
19260218 234 77     ok
                    3
                    ok
19310328 174 46     2
```

When the value in column B is numerical, I have a conditional format that that entire row is colored red. If it's possible, I would need the following in vba:

If the value in column B is numerical AND the cell in column A (on the same row) is empty, copy the previously encountered value from column A to the target row.
In this case (not counting the header): B2 = numerical AND A2 = emtpy, so copy A1 to A2

B4 is also numerical, but since A4 is not empty, nothing needs to be copied.

Is this thing possible for an entire worksheet that changes in the number of rows? If so, how?

Thank you for your assistance. If I need to explain further, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: You have explained what you want, but what have you tried? We are here to help you solve a problem, but this is not a script writing service.

Comment: I had gotten to the point where my script could correctly identify the parameters (which cells need to be empty and which not, and so on). But I had no idea about how to copy the correct data. 
My apologies for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this VBA code in the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet
cellempty = False
i = 1
'Check the max. number of rows
While cellempty = False
    a = Cells(i, 2)
    If a = "" Then
        finalrow = i - 1
        cellempty = True
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
'Going row by row
For i = 1 To finalrow
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 2)) Then 'check if cell in column B is numeric
        If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then 'check if cell in column A is empty
            'goes upward on column A to find a non-empty value
            For j = i To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(j, 1) <> "" Then
                    Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) 'copy value to cell
                    j = 1
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

it's a very basic thing that you can refine to be more adapted to your needs. It assumes that the data is in columns A and B, and will be executed whenever is a change on the worksheet.

Comment: I was indeed able to use this code, modify it and have it work. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can input this in cell C2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),IF(A2="",A1,A2),IF(A2="","",A2))
```

and copy the formula to C3, C4, C5...

Now the column C will have the information the way you want it

For cell C1 input:

```
=IF(A1="","",A1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I do need a solution in VBA.
And it might just be that I need to look for a value in A1, and then copy it to A6 (because B6 is numerical). The rows aren't always above each other.